# Unity3D: Player accelerates indefinitely when jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hello people,**

I have a problem with my PlayerController in Unity3D. As stated in the title my player accelerates indefinitely when pressing the "jump"-key. My real problem here is, that this is only the case if I export the scenes and then start the game. If I just start the scene in the Unity Editor everything just works fine. So its probably not the code?

I do recall, that a friend of mine experienced the same problem a while ago while testing one of the earlier versions of the game while I couldn't reproduce it on my machine. Unfortunatly he didn't have time to review this version until now.
Just since I switched to a new developing station I experience that problem.
If I run the game on my laptop it runs just fine (not mentioning the 3 FPS I have, but it does work ^^).

All 4 PCs mentioned above run Windows 10, if that helps.

This is the code I use for my jump method:

```
private void Jump()
    {
        if (groundDetector.currentCollisions.Count != 0)
        {  
            Vector3 vel = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, 0, rigidbody.velocity.z);
            rigidbody.velocity = vel;
            Vector3 jumpForce = new Vector3(0, jumpPower, 0);
            rigidbody.AddForce(jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }
```

I would be really thankfull if someone could help my with this problem, since I already spend some hours of googling time and didn't find a clue at all, noone seems to have the same problem...

Thanks in advance!
Lukas

Comment: You don't want to execute this function more than once if jumping, so you can for instance add "isAirborne != 2" in the `if`

Comment: It's unclear what `isAirborne = 2` means. Why isn't `isAirborne` a `bool`?

Comment: Oh, thats just a leftover from an earlier stage of development. I since reworked the way how isAirborne is handled, so this line of code is irrelevant. It should change nothing to delete it. I will however try another build without that line.

Comment: I tried another build, but still have the exact same issue...
I also deleted the line from the code above, so this doesn't lead to more confusion. Im sorry for having that in the code in the first place.

Comment: Where is the `Jump` method called?

Comment: In the Update() method, inside an if statement with Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")